# Sharepoint online groups: how much space is allocated to each?

Tags: office-365, groups

Since now groups are sort of like site collections but they do not show up in the site collection lists in admin center, how it is possible to mnanage the space allocated to each?

Answer (score 2):

Office 365 groups have a 1TB default quota that counts against the pooled tenant storage. The updated [SharePoint Online Management shell](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35588) will allow you to do a set-sposite command on the group and assign a new quota.

I have not seen anything yet that will allow you to set a lower default quota yet.

Comment: the amount of space taken up by groups will show up in the global count of space occupied in the site collections sections of the tenancy?

Comment: it should be included in that yes, based on them saying it counts against tenant pooled storage